# Javascript object with key value pairs, how to separate each pair as individual object?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a javascript object with key value pairs i want to separate each pair as individual object and push it to a array how do i do that?

```
 var obj = new Object();
 obj = {
      v1 : 'k1',
      v2 : 'k2',
      v3 : 'k3'
    }

    a =[];

Object.entries(obj).forEach(
  ([key, value]) => {
    a.push({key : value});
  });
console.log(a);
```

This is my expected output:

```
[{v1 : 'k1'}, {v2 : 'k2'}, {v3 : 'k3'}]
```

Comment: i want this as output :
    [{v1 : 'k1'}, {v2 : 'k2'}, {v3 : 'k3'}]

Answer (score 2):

You have almost got it. To create a dynamic property from a variable (it's called [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)), you need to add `[]` around `key`. Otherwise, it just creates an object with just "key" as the `key`:

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    a.push({ [key] : value });
    //        ↑↑
  });
```

or, much simpler using `map`:

```js
const obj = {v1:'k1',v2:'k2',v3:'k3'},
      a = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({[key] : value}));

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj =  { v1 : 'k1', v2 : 'k2', v3 : 'k3' }

var result = []
for(var i in obj) result.push([i, obj[i]])


console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A more functional way to approach this would be to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the object entries to produce a new array of objects.

```js
var obj =  { v1 : 'k1', v2 : 'k2', v3 : 'k3' }

const out  = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));

console.log(out);
```