# key value in the object is not populating correctly

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, key-value

I am trying to store each property of the object into an Object array.

Ex :

```
{
  a: b,
  c: d
}
```

to

```
[
  { a: b }, 
  { c: d }
]
```

Below is the code which I am trying to execute.

```js
var a = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b"
}

var newA = []

for (var keys in a) {
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
    newA.push({
      keys: a[keys]
    })
  }
}

console.log(newA)
```

When i am pushing the property to the "newA" array the key value is pushed as "keys" instead of the original key name.

Result: [{keys: a},{keys:b}]

Expected: [{a:a},{b:b}]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript object with key value pairs, how to separate each pair as individual object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160279/javascript-object-with-key-value-pairs-how-to-separate-each-pair-as-individual)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) . Also I believe `hasOwnProperty()` is redundant in your code, at least for this particular example, where your object doesn't inherit enumerable properties. Look at the [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description) description. So you can go with:

```
for (const key in a)
{
    newA.push({[key] : a[key]});
}
```

However, as an alternative you can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var a = {a : "a", b : "b"};

let res = Object.entries(a).map(([k,v]) => ({[k]: v}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Computed property names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) by placing brackets around the variable **keys**  within your push statement:

```
newA.push({ [keys]: a[keys] })
```

Example in action:

```js
var a = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b"
}

var newA = []

for (var keys in a) {
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
    newA.push({
      [keys]: a[keys]
    })
  }
}

console.log(newA)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help:)